# Merge one SQL column into another and remove duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I've searched high and low and maybe I have found the answer but I cannot implement it so if you could help that would be great.

I have two columns in my database table:

```
USERID | FRIENDID
-------+----------
887    | 553
54     | 887
23     | 887
```

I need to get the data for say `USERID = 887`.

This is my query:

```
SELECT  
    `userid`, `friend_id`
FROM  
    friends 
WHERE 
    userid = 887 or FRIENDID = 887
```

Now this is returning that data as I expect, however I need the data to be presented like this:

```
IDS
------    
887 
553 
887
887     
54
23
```

So both columns of data are pushed into one, and if possible remove the duplicate IDs of 887

Comment: `mabye[sic] I have found the answer but I cannot implement it` - what is the answer you found?

Comment: That would require it to be done in PHP or with a `UNION` between the two different queries.  I really can't see why you'd want to include the user in their own friend list or show their friend list when someone else wants to simply view them but it's your site after all.

Comment: I can not find the rational behind presented desired output. what is the meaning of those 6 numbers?

Comment: Look at MySQLs [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) Syntax. You do 2 queries, 1 for `user_id` and 1 for `friend_id` and join them using `UNION` which will give you only the unique values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a test table and added some extra values to make sure it only returns what you would like.

All you need to do is use a union to get the distinct values. In the first select you get the UserID and in the second select you get the FriendID. You use the same WHERE clause in both so that you can get all the values you would like.

```
CREATE TABLE #Friends (UserID INT, FriendID INT)

INSERT INTO #Friends 
VALUES (887,553),(54,887),(23,887),(74,66),(89,49)

SELECT * FROM #Friends

SELECT IDs = UserID
FROM #Friends 
WHERE UserID = 887 OR FriendID = 887

UNION 

SELECT IDs = FriendID
FROM #Friends 
WHERE UserID = 887 OR FriendID = 887
```

Comment: If this code works, consider adding some text explaining why it solves the OP's issue.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code as well and added an explanation as to why it works :)

Answer (score 2):

```
(select userid as id from friends where userid = XXX)
union
(select friend_id as id from friends where friend_id = XXX)
```

Explanation: Use `union` for combining results of the two queries for `userid` and `friend_id`. <strike>Use `distinct` to remove duplicates.</strike>. `UNION` already does a distinct over the result set.

Comment: The outer `DISTINCT` is not necessarily as [`The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result.`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

Comment: @Sean: Indeed. Modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The other examples wouldn't return what you wanted, one list of distinct id's

```
with cte as (
   SELECT  
       userid id
   FROM  
       friends 
   WHERE 
       userid = 887 or FRIENDID = 887
   UNION
   SELECT  
       FRIENDID
   FROM  
       friends 
   WHERE 
       userid = 887 or FRIENDID = 887
) SELECT DISTINCT id From cte
```